# How Scroll to a div in ng-template?

Tags: javascript, angular, ng-template, ng-modal

Im using ngb modal to for a pop up where the content is set inside a `<ng-template>`. On submit (on error)  I need to automatically scroll down to the error section. I tried @viewchild on the `<div #error>` but since its part of the template the viewchild value is  always undefined.
What would be the best way to access a div inside a template or to scroll automatically on ngbmodal to ots scroll height ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use Angular for that. You can accomplish that with pure Javascript.

You could use `<my-element id="someid"></my-element>`

And then, with pure javascript, `document.getElementById("someid").scrollIntoView()`

Comment: I think you are right ..Using pure JS works.. Thank you!